# CSS "overflow" property for elements other than DIVs

Tags: css, html, overflow

**Does the CSS property `overflow` apply to `div`s, or is there a list of other HTML elements that support this property?**

I tried to use:

```
<span style="overflow:auto;"><img src="hs.gif" alt="Horizontal Scroll"></span>
```

But it doesn't seem to apply an horizontal scroll bar when the contents are partially hidden, as in the case of a `div`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works on most* elements; the problem is that your `<span>` expands to contain your image. (What width would it need for there to be a scrollbar?) Give it a width (and to do that, it can't be inline, either; the default for `<span>`s):

```
<span style="overflow: auto; display: inline-block; width: 100px;">
```

[And now it works.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/GgFCk/)

<sup>* most: block-level elements, table cells, inline-table and inline-block elements. [Documentation here.](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/overflow)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

`overflow` applies to [*block* level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements).

Span is an *inline* element (as is `img`), so it will not apply.

Answer (score 1):

**Initial value:visible

Applies to: block and inline-block elements, table cells

Inherited : no

Media:visual

Computed value as specified**

for more details https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/overflow